# Definition of derivative on non-open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I’ve got confused by this basic definition from PDE: I knew the definition of all kinds of derivative on an open set, but what is the partial derivative on the boundary? For example, the heat equation satisfies on a closed rectangle $0\leq x \leq l, 0 \leq t \leq T$ and let’s say the solution $u$ is smooth, then what is the smoothness at a vertex or on the boundary? And under what conditions can we extend the domain to an open set such that the original relation satisfies at every point of the original set? Can anyone explain this basic definition.. The textbook doesn’t seem to explain this explicitly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if a point, p, in your domain is a limit of interior points, then you can define the derivative of f at p as the derivative at p of any extension of f to a neighborhood of p. you can use the fact that p is a limit of interior points to show that this definition doesn't depend on the extension you choose.

Comment: @Tim kinsella :Thank you, do you have a reference of this technique?